# Prime numbers and a positive definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, prime-numbers, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

Probably this has nothing to do with prime numbers, I just [experimented a little bit](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kEFrwyAYhu-F_gchF7WSLNut0NsYPeS0axjBLNZKzJfMaOnPn9VYuoYZMPr6fK-vXydO6HjEQPbbDfLDCOsMoNkNuC7zl6JHp9GgHilAhoMUuGSwK8kX2W5uX-fLq2pVHhx34jrhsCJUj3JZxrpY-eNGi7VmzrFnB609XDjn50T3fWSfST60HUectWj_6MhpW8jvDvsDQunr3SY4_7UAe24mowbhTyiFRIbb_yV9FygNv_igTGt0QLOSA_cb5_ymqpKVNHxYmQ3cGnXFdX1_WQgbOs5XHQ9yu5KZUSAPn-8fIcaNgUemfCvTrZkPDhYvUUgUowZsUXM1N9M4K6suovHBFSgrcIKzRM-jsaJLVrlQUsCFaydmz5JfORGoRQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) with it and wanted to share it, in case someone has an idea.

Let

$$p_n := n\text{-th prime number , }[a,b]:= \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2}$$

Then (?) for every natural number $n$ the matrix

$$G_n := \left (\frac{p_{[a,b]}^{[a,b]}}{p_{[a,b]+1}^{[a,b]+1}} \right )_{1\le a,b \le n}$$

is positive definite?

Comment: Interesting. It looks like the first few matrices are [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), but for $n \ge 6$ this breaks down, so something slightly more subtle is needed.

Comment: @A.Thibault: Thanks for your interest in this question.